# Mocha Test Execution | No status for individual test cases

Tags: javascript, mocha.js

I have started writing test cases for my REST API's. Below is the code. I am not getting status of individual test cases (pass/fail , test case name etc). I understand there is something very trivial which I am missing

Code :

```
**var supertest = require("supertest");
var should = require("should");
// This agent refers to PORT where program is runninng.
var server = supertest.agent("http://localhost:1337");
// UNIT test begin
describe("SAMPLE unit test",function(){
  // #1 should return home page
  it("should return login details",function(done){
    // calling Login api
    server
    .post('/login')
    .send({ loginid: "8787878787", password : "temp"})
    .expect("Content-type",/json/)
    .expect(200)
    .end(function(err,res){
      res.status.should.equal(200);
      res.body.notFound.should.equal(false);
      res.body.data.customerId.should.equal(20);
      done();
    });
  });
  it("should return no active user",function(done){
    // calling home page api
    server
    .post('/login')
    .send({ loginid: "8787878787", password : "temp1"})
    .expect("Content-type",/json/)
    .end(function(err,res){
      res.body.notFound.should.equal(true);
      done();
    });
  });
});**
```

On command prompt this is the output. It is not showing individual test case status (name- what is described in "it" block,how much time each test case has taken etc)

**.
  2 passing (7s)**

Let me know how to display individual test case status.

Comment: Thanks ! This is resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Mocha has a few options for displaying tests as they run. I think, for your case, you might want to go with `List`. There are more options [here](https://mochajs.org/#reporters).

So, in the terminal, you would invoke your tests with - 
`mocha -R list tests/test.js`

You can also use a global config for mocha to have you from writing the reporter type each time and definitely if you have more than one test file.